# How to format - add spaces to - numeric and telephone number output data from Contact Form 7 - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, output, contact-form-7

I have set up a couple of fields in my contact form using the Contact Form 7 plugin in Wordpress. One of the fields is a telephone number field. When people enter a phone number, unless they intentionally enter spaces, hyphens or parentheses, it will output the number as a 10-digit string with no spaces, such as 4445551212 instead of what I would prefer, which would be something more easy to read, like 444-555-1212 or even just 444 555 1212.

I posted my question on how to do this to the CF7 forums in Wordpress. What I received was a bit of code that would add a comma every 3 digits, which is not helpful.

I was sent to this page on how to customize mail-tag replacement: https://contactform7.com/2019/12/08/customizing-mail-tag-replacement/

Specifically, the code I added, which did work in adding commas, was this...

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
 
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( 'your-number' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
      if ( is_numeric( $submitted ) ) {
        $replaced = number_format( $submitted );
      }
    }
 
    return $replaced;
  },
 
  10, 4
);
```

However, like I mentioned, adding commas doesn't do me any good.

So, the trick would be to add spaces and even dashes if the user did not add those, but not to change anything if the user did actually add spaces, dashes or parentheses.

Also, this only changes the output of what gets sent to email. That would be a great start, but I'm wondering if there's a way to change the output that gets sent to other data mediums. For example, I am using a CF7 to PDF plugin that takes the data from a form and outputs it to a PDF that gets attached to the email that is sent.

Any ideas on where I could start on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can achieve this:

```php
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php or a custom plugin

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', 'cf7_custom_format_phone_number', 10, 4 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'cf7_custom_format_phone_number_in_mail', 10, 3 );

function cf7_custom_format_phone_number( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( 'your-number' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
        // Remove non-numeric characters to get a clean phone number
        $cleaned_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $submitted);
        
        // Format the phone number
        if ( strlen($cleaned_number) === 10 ) {
            $formatted_number = substr($cleaned_number, 0, 3) . '-' . substr($cleaned_number, 3, 3) . '-' . substr($cleaned_number, 6, 4);
            $replaced = $formatted_number;
        }
    }

    return $replaced;
}

function cf7_custom_format_phone_number_in_mail( $components, $contact_form, $mail ) {
    // Check if there is a phone number field in the form
    if ( isset( $components['body'] ) && isset( $components['raw'] ) ) {
        // Apply formatting only to the email content, not the raw data
        $formatted_content = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\[your-number([^\]]*)\]/',
            function ( $matches ) {
                $number = $matches[1];
                $cleaned_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $number);
                
                if ( strlen($cleaned_number) === 10 ) {
                    return substr($cleaned_number, 0, 3) . '-' . substr($cleaned_number, 3, 3) . '-' . substr($cleaned_number, 6, 4);
                }
                
                return $number; // Return the original number if it doesn't match the format
            },
            $components['body']
        );
        
        // Update the email content with the formatted phone number
        $components['body'] = $formatted_content;
    }

    return $components;
}
```

1. The `custom_format_phone_number` function formats the phone number as desired. It first removes any non-numeric characters, then checks if the cleaned number has 10 digits before formatting it with dashes. This function is used to modify the data that will be displayed in the email.
2. The `custom_format_phone_number_in_mail` function is used to modify the email content. It uses a regular expression to find the `[your-number]` mail tag and replaces it with the properly formatted phone number.
3. Both of these functions work together to ensure that the formatting is applied to the email content and not just to the raw data. This will ensure that the CF7 to PDF plugin will also receive the properly formatted phone number.

Make sure to replace `'your-number'` with the actual name or label of your phone number field in Contact Form 7. Also, remember to test thoroughly to ensure that the code works as expected in your specific setup.

Output:
[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so very much. It worked perfectly for the phone number output. I am also trying to create a situation where, if someone submits a larger number - like a 16-digit credit card number for example, it would separate the string of numbers into groups of 4 digits. I will play around with the code you provided to see if I can come up with that result, but if you have an idea on how to get that result, I'd appreciate it! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Yes you can just play with this snippet and it will work.

// Format the phone number 10 instead of 16
// substr($cleaned_number, 0, 3) to substr($cleaned_number, 0, 4)

it will work. Note: Update both place; and try if still not working then let me know.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again! I was able to figure out how to edit it so that it does whatever I need it to! I appreciate the help.